# Refresh page when new price is available in Bottle (Python)

Tags: python, html, bottle

I am making a Bitcoin/Ethereum price ticker webpage in Bottle for Python for my company and I want to refresh the page when new prices are available. I am pulling the price data from an API endpoint available through the company. I have hidden the URL to this for security purposes.

templates.py

```
from bottle import run, get, route, template
import requests

main_api = #url to company's api

def isDataValid(json_data):
  if "status" in json_data:
      return True
  else:
      return False

def returnPrices(coin, curr):
  url = main_api + coin + curr
  json_data = requests.get(url).json()
  prices = {}

  if isDataValid(json_data) == True:
      buy_price = str(json_data["data"]["buy_price"])
      sell_price = str(json_data["data"]["sell_price"])
      prices = [buy_price, sell_price]
  else:
      prices = ["Error"]

  return prices

@route('/')
def index():

  pricesBTC = returnPrices('BTC','USD')
  pricesETH = returnPrices('ETH','USD')
  btc_buy_price = pricesBTC[0]
  btc_sell_price = pricesBTC[1]

  eth_buy_price = pricesETH[0]
  eth_sell_price = pricesETH[1]

  return template('index', btc_buy_price = btc_buy_price, btc_sell_price = btc_sell_price, eth_buy_price = eth_buy_price, eth_sell_price = eth_sell_price)

run(reLoader = True, debug = True)
```

So how do I refresh the page everytime prices change? I think the prices for ETH and BTC don't change at the same time, so I might have to refresh whenever either of them change. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible without some browser-side JavaScript.
For example, you create additional Bottle endpoint that provides updated data as JSON, and an in-browser script polls that data via AJAX and update the respective html page elements.
As far as JS concerned, there are too many ways to implement this functionality, from simple JQuery to JS frameworks like Angular and Vue.js.